# facing lost context while making 3dwebsite with three js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

```
`import React, {useRef} from 'react'
import { useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';
import {easing} from 'maath';
import { useSnapshot } from 'valtio';
import state from '../store';
const CameraRig = ({children}) => {
  
  const group = useRef();
  const snap = useSnapshot(state);

  useFrame((state, delta) =>{
    const isBreakPoint = window.innerWidth <= 1260;
    const isMobile = window.innerWidth <= 600;
    let targetPosition = [-0.4, 0, 2];
    if(snap.intro){
      if(isBreakPoint) targetPosition = [0, 0, 2];
      if(isMobile) targetPosition = [0, 0.2, 2.5];
    } else {
      if(isMobile) targetPosition = [0, 0, 2.5];
      else targetPosition = [0, 0, 2];
    }
    easing.damp3(state.camera.position, targetPosition, 0.25, delta)
    easing.dampE(
      group.current.rotation,
      [state.pointer.y / 10, -state.pointer.x / 5, 0],
      0.25,
      delta
    )
  })


  return <group ref={group}>{children}</group>
}

export default CameraRig`
```

am facing an error while running this code I think problem appearing in children passing and also the context will be lost,would you please help me out to resolve this problem or where the problem occurs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.